# Should I set my TextView colours if my background colour is not set?

Tags: android

When I comes to specifying colours for an application, I recently came across `@android:color`. Is it recommended to try to always use predefined system colors?

I changed the colours of some of my labels to something brighter, so that they'll stand out against the black background. But then I start to wonder... would themes/skins (not familiar with those) and such cause the default background colour to be something other than black?

If so... what's the proper way to deal with colouring one's widgets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I don't know Android.  This is general UI design advice.)

If you set the foreground color, you should change the background color as well.  Otherwise, if someone's background is set to something wacky, your labels could wind up invisible -- or at the least, hard to see -- and you'll have defeated the purpose of using different colors.

I'd recommend you leave the colors as they are, unless you can change the background color as well.  Perhaps using a bold font or something would be a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

You've got 2 options: 
1) define explicitly fore/background colors of all of your elements
2) use only default colors, so when the user change its theme, everything will change accordingly. Personally, i prefer this way, but be careful if your UI's got some images

Be consistent, so you'll avoid issues when users change its themes. choose one and back to work!